# Are techniques (like queue, lock, ...) required when reading from a thread in one direction

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I want to read current results from a thread (which has a high sample rate). The thread reads sensor values from the hardware with a looptime of 10 ms -> 1 ms work and 9 ms sleep but it varies a bit (+/- 0.5 ms). In my first approach I used a Lifo-Queue. Thread writes to the queue and main program reads it and empty the queue after reading. That worked well then. Until I noticed that it came after a long time of the program to call delays. 
As far as I understood the problem. Every queue.put () uses fresh memory and queue.get () + queue.clear () makages memory to be purged. The memory is then cleaned up at certain intervals. and the cleaner comes with different runtime. And that generates the sporadic call delays.

Now I have asked myself if the queue makes sense, in this application case. So I created a threading.Object and built in addition to init () and run () a get_value_function("get_io_data"), which is called by the main process. The main process has no possibility to write back to the sensor data. The writing back is not needed. Only reading in one direction from the thread into the main process. The GIL should actually prevent simultaneous reading and writing. And the worst that can happen is that an old value has been read. 
Is the assumption correct? Have I overlooked something or not understood?

This code is a schematic representation to make the question easier to understand. He is not functional!

```py
import threading
import time
from My_modul import controller_step


class IOboard(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name="IO_board")
        self.__data__ = {}

    def run(self):

        self.init_hardware()

        while True:

            self.data.update(self.read_all_sensors())
            self.data.update(self.read_all_aktors())
            time.sleep(0.09)

    def get_io_data(self):
        return self.__data__


def main():
    app = IOboard()
    app.start()

    while True:
        input_data_now = app.get_io_data()

        out_put_data = controller_step(input_data_now)

        print(time.time() + out_put_data)

        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my first stack overflow question. I hope that I could understand myself. I want an answer: if with build-in-call a thread can query a varibale without violating the python-law or linux-law

Comment: the problem is when queue is empty or getting empty, what would happen when testing for emptiness of something getting added an entry?

Comment: python```         if not self.queue_io_miso_sensors.empty():
            # Get value from the queue and update it to the dictionary
            self.dic_transfer_sensors.update(self.queue_io_miso_sensors.get(block=False)) ```

Comment: Python's built-in queues are thread-safe, which is why that version worked. Reading from "one direction" isn't really relevant. Something else has to be producing the data and the issue with concurrency is to prevent issues that can arise when data is being read at the same time more data is being added.

Comment: ...so the answer is "yes", you do need to use those techniques if you're not using something like a `Queue` class that handles it for you.